# How to store date & time in DECIMAL(18,3)?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am currently working with a database scheme that contains a DECIMAL(18,3) column that is supposed to contain date and time. Sadly, I do not have any example data and need to create it myself.

However, I do not know how to correctly format the dates I want to insert, because when you add together year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds, you get 14, if you add 3 more numbers for the milliseconds you get 17. Where is the eighteenth number hiding from me?

Comment: Maybe they wanted to be Y10K compliant?

Comment: I wouldn't put it past them.

Comment: Use something like DECIMAL(18,4)... It gives you a total of 18 digits, 4 of which after the decimal point (and 14 before the decimal point)..

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has two date+time formats:

For 1-second resolution, use the datatype `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW() AS sample_DATETIME, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS sample_TIMESTAMP;
+---------------------+------------------+
| sample_DATETIME     | sample_TIMESTAMP |
+---------------------+------------------+
| 2018-11-26 12:45:15 |       1543265115 |
+---------------------+------------------+
```

To include milliseconds, use `DATETIME(3)` or `TIMESTAMP(3)`:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(3) AS sample_DATETIME;
+-------------------------+
| sample_DATETIME         |
+-------------------------+
| 2018-11-26 12:46:35.093 |
+-------------------------+
```

Think of `DATETIME` as a picture of the clock.  Note that it has suitable hiccups when Daylight Savings comes or goes.

`TIMESTAMP` is essentially UTC, but converted from/to your timezone.

I have not heard of anyone using `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from the schema owners: Apparently it's [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: Seems like `DECIMAL(13,3)` (8 bytes, 10 digits before the decimal point, 3 after) would suffice.  For example, the current time is `1543423205.661`.  That's seconds since 1970.

Comment: The schema owner is confident that the application will work until the heat death of the universe.

Comment: Well, they're wrong about that.  On January 19, 2038, "the Unix Time Stamp will cease to work due to a 32-bit overflow."